Product:114 Uncaught ReferenceError: signalR is not defined at Product:114:26
Product:114  Uncaught ReferenceError: signalR is not defined
at Product:114:26
Tried to inspectf it and the source say its in this line:
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chat").build();
and this is how I wrote the source:
also checked the ItemGroup and these are the packages there:




Could you describe the issue clearly ?It's hard for us to understand your question.
